# What is the math font in this equation? (similar to mathcal)

Tags: fonts, equations

Anyone knows the font used for M in the attached equation? Thanks. Looks similar to **mathcal**.

[image]

Reference:
Rouder, J. N., Morey, R. D., Speckman, P. L., & Province, J. M. (2012). Default Bayes factors for ANOVA designs. *Journal of Mathematical Psychology, 56*(5), 356-374.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does [this help?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

Comment: If you want to look up a supplemental math alphabet, you can compare to the specimens [in the `mathalpha` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf).